# VBA Copy and Paste to Row +1 below

Tags: vba, excel, copy, copy-paste

I'm trying to write some code that will copy and paste data in cells A3:A6 to A8:A11 and then when run again it will paste it the row +1 beneath, so the next time it's run the data in A8:A11 will be copy and pasted into A13:A16 and the next time after that it's run it will paste the data in A13:16 to A18:21 and so on.

The below is what I've tried to come up with but I might be quite a way off, any guidance will be appreciated:

```
Sub RollFile()

Dim UsdRows As Long

UsdRows = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlToUp).Row
With Range(Cells(1, UsdRows), Cells(UsdRows, 1))
  .Copy .Offset(, 1)
  .Value = .Value
  .Offset(-1, 1)(1).Select
End With

End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: `xlUp`, not `xlToUp`. Also, your `Offset(, 1)` is offsetting by 1 column - the row offset is the first argument.

Comment: The 2nd argument of `Cells` is the column number, why `Cells(1, UsdRows)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this

```
Sub RollFile()

    With Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) ' reference column A last not empty cell
        With Range(.End(xlUp), .Cells) ' reference the range from referenced cell up to last adjacent one
            .Offset(.Rows.Count + 1).Value = .Value ' copy referenced range values to a range two row below its end
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RollFile()
    Const RowsToCopy As Long = 4 'amount of rows that should be copied

    Dim LastCell As Range
    Set LastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp) 'last cell in col A

    With LastCell.Offset(RowOffset:=-RowsToCopy + 1).Resize(RowSize:=RowsToCopy) '= last 4 cells (4 = RowsToCopy)
        .Copy LastCell.Offset(RowOffset:=2)
        .Value = .Value 'not needed I think
    End With
End Sub
```

It looks for the last used cell in column A. Then selects the previous 4 cells from there and copies that 2 rows below.

Note that I think `.Value = .Value` is not needed at all because that only makes sense if formulas were copied that need to be transformed into values.

Comment: this has copied A4:A6 into cells A7:A9 - for example in cells A3,A4,A5 and A5 contain text A,B,C and D - this has put the text B, C and D into cells A7:A9. I need it so that A, B, C and D goes into A8:A11. Thanks